# zstd: error 70 : Write error : Broken pipe (cannot write decoded block)

Tags: cmd, pipe, ag, zstandard, zstd

I'm trying through Windows terminal to decompress a large number of compressed files with zstd v1.4.0 and then 'ag' search over :

`zstd -dc -r . | ag -z -i "term"`

It gives me the following error while proceeding :

> zstd: error 70 : Write error : Broken pipe (cannot write decoded block)

I have spent hours looking for a solution, tried different options for the `zstd` command but can't solve this.

Comment: This may indicate that ag is quitting, can you normally check if `ag -z "term" <file>` is working for you?

Comment: It gives me errors : `ERR: Cannot decompress zipped file` or `ERR: Zip files not yet supported`

Comment: Yes, so zip and gzip is different and I believe ag supports gzip not zip

Comment: @titibouboul you should try to narrow the problem, is it working with 1 compressed file ? maybe using powershell is different (in the past cmd pipe was: write to a temporary file and reading it) ?

Answer (score 3):

If you like to search over uncompressed files, you should use :

```
zstd -dc -r . | ag -i "term"
```

`zstd` will uncompress the supported files and `ag` will search over it (your command try to uncompress twice, once with zstd, once with ag)

You can get the supported format using `zstd -vV` that should give you something like :

> ```
> *** zstd command line interface 64-bits v1.4.0, by Yann Collet ***
> *** supports: zstd, zstd legacy v0.5+, gzip
> ```

Note: The `zstd` version I tried doesnot support zip.

You can get the supported compressed format by `ag` using `ag -V`, that should give something like :

> ```
> ag version 2.1.0
>
> Features:
>   +jit +lzma +zlib
> ```

Note: The `ag` version I tried doesnot support zip.

Comment: Thanks for this lengthy answer, it's really interesting. I've tried first solution, ie. removing `-z` from formula and I have same error.

Comment: @titibouboul: This is strange because in [decompress.c](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/src/decompress.c) the message `Zip files not yet supported` is printed in method `decompress`and this method is called only when `-z` is used [search.c](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/src/search.c)

Comment: I'm referring to the original error I'm trying to fix : `zstd: error 70 : Write error : Broken pipe (cannot write decoded block)`